# Can serializable class be used as command class

Tags: spring

I am using spring mvc 2.5 . I have a serializable class (For instance A class), but now I use this A class as command class.

Can a serializable class be used as command class? If yes, how?

In servlet, I define this A class as command class, in formbacking method, I created object from this A class but in formbacking, when I try to return the object created by this A class, it is not successful.

Additionally, I want to save data coming from jsp file into database by using A.hbm.xml

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. It is not important that class is serilizable class or not. Mapping can be done correctly.